# How to allow api access to android or ios app only(laravel)?

Tags: php, api, security, laravel

I am implementing an api in laravel.

what I want is my api should not be accessible from anywhere except from android/ios app.I googled and came to know that I can make use of API KEY.

But I am not sure is it correct way or not.

Currently using OAuth2 for user authentication.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to create a token for each user, save it in the client's device , verify it in each request that the client makes.

So basically you want to:

- Make a **column** for the token in the users table
- **generate the token** when the user registers
- make a **login** route so that the user would login with his email,password and he will getback the token to store in the device
- make a **middleware** that would check for the token in each request ( except for the login )

I wrote an article of the exact same thing you want

https://medium.com/@alhasaniq/how-to-add-token-based-authentication-to-laravel-app-s-to-use-in-api-s-1a0e45f9106#.15e3f9quu

Comment: @AlhasanIQ thank you for responding. I saw your article and it is very informative but my question is basically How can I filter out request which are from android or iOS only?

Comment: you can do it in 2 ways: 
1. by user agents (if it is applied on the http request by the mobile ) using this `$request->header('User-Agent');`
2. by sending something like `'device' : 'ios` in every request from the client to the server
otherwise you cant really identify the request

Comment: How about using apikey. suppose I give api key to app developer and each time developer makes request he will pass api key also and from api key we can detect client. just an abstract idea. can we use it?

Comment: yes, you can add something like `_ios` or `_android` to the token 
its a matter of preference