# How to allow laravel api only for mobile app?

Tags: php, laravel, api, react-native

I'm building a mobile app using react native + Laravel API. Mobile app can access by public with out registration/login.

What I want is, How to allow API access only for mobile app. API should not allow from web.

Comment: You can refer this, may be it will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404062/how-to-allow-api-access-to-android-or-ios-app-onlylaravel

Comment: You have to be more specific. Does your app have users? Do they register in the app? Please add some details to the question.

Comment: @gauri , I looked that previously. That is works with user login.

Comment: You can consider adding a custom Header to the Http Request.

Comment: @ryantxr , I have mentioned that in my question. mobile app can access by public  without registration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this Laravel component which you can install with Composer.
This package provides the ability to use a single API key which you put in your .env file.

https://github.com/erjanmx/laravel-api-auth

I assume you don't want to go to the trouble of building this yourself.

```
composer require erjanmx/laravel-api-auth
```

Publish the Package configuration

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Apiauth\Laravel\CAuthServiceProvider"
```

Add this to .env

```
REMOTE_APP_TOKEN=<secret-token>
```

Add 'apiauth:REMOTE_APP' middleware to your routes

```
// /routes/api.php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => ['apiauth:REMOTE_APP']], function () {
     // your routes
});
```

Your urls within your group is accessible only if a valid secret-token is provided

- In GET or POST request
- In request header as Authorization Bearer
- In json raw body

Secret-token is any string you generate. Use the same secret-token in the mobile app and the Laravel side.

Comment: Great. I will look into this.

Comment: what if someone knows that secret-token and api url and makes a api request with this secret-token from any websites? then anyone can use and abuse the api if they know that secret-token.

Comment: @developer that is true of any API key. You should always take care to protect your API keys.

Answer (score 2):

An API is a component seperate from the front end. So it doesn’t have any way to know what kind of platform is trying to access it, unless of course the frontend gives some information to the API (which is not trustworthy).

So what I mean by this is you can try to pass a custom parameter or a header field indicating the request from the mobile and do not include that in requests from other platforms. However this is just one of the many ways to do it.

Comment: @sapnesh-saik I will try that